# R lattice wireframe color scale similar across plots

Tags: r, lattice, wireframe

Is there a way to change the drape color scale in lattice: wireplot?  I have a series of plots and would like to adjust the colors so they each show the same color scale.  I am able to change the z axis scale, but that only makes it so the surface itself moves up and down, not the color scale.  Is there a keyword I am missing when looking it up?

```
wireframe(InitFe2solid.ug.gdw~Depth*Distance,
          allplatesdata[allplatesdata$UseMonth=="August", ],
          drape = TRUE,
          colorkey = TRUE,
          zlab = list("Sulfate uM", rot = 90),
          zlim = range(seq(0.0, 4)))
```

Comment: It seems to be the line      at=do.breaks(c(0,14),100),

Answer (score 1):

Adding the line fixes it

```
 at=do.breaks(c(0,14),100)
```